# Функция mail() отправляет. На почту gmail приходит пустое письмо!

Tags: email, php, gmail

Доброго времени! Сразу к делу! Отправляю письмо таким образом:

```
 $sendz = mail($email, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane; Charset=utf-8\r\n\n\n");
```

И далее такая балалайка: если функция шлет письмо на mail.ru, то письмо приходит прекрасно! Без ошибок! НО ежели слать на gmail, то не отображается текст письма (с заголовком письма порядок при том), вместо текста мне предлогают скачать файл noname без какого-либо разрешения.

Как быть? Зарание благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо изменить:

```
text/plane
```

На:

```
text/plain
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$from_mail."\r\n";

mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```